# Stopping rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to be able to get a different number from

```
rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
```

but it keeps giving me a number every time causing different statements to be true.

```
if (rnd == 1) {
        chest1.gotoAndStop("chest");
    }
    if (rnd == 2) {
        chest2.gotoAndStop("chest");
    }
    if (rnd == 3) {
        chest3.gotoAndStop("chest");
    }
```

I want it so it does it once, and then gives me another number after i successful returned the chest causing another chest to appear.  But its not, just makes the same chest appear :(

Comment: what does `trace(rnd);` show?

Comment: You might want to use int variable **var rnd:int = Math.random() * 3 + 1;** but otherwise there's no problem with the code, unless you run it several times somehow.

Comment: Make sure you are calling "rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;" every time you want to get a new chest, and you are not just using the same variable value, also make sure you arent doing something silly like using the same chest for 1,2, and 3. Add a trace in before your if statement and after you get a random number to see when things are getting called and what the values are. Good Luck!

Comment: Andrew if you wrote that as an Answer, i would have gave you the solution check mark.  Your method is the way I really ended up doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1)
{
case 1:
    chest1.gotoAndStop("chest");
    break;
case 2:
    chest2.gotoAndStop("chest");
    break;
case 3:
    chest3.gotoAndStop("chest");
    break;
}
```